# How to port older version of Angular.Dart code to Angular.Dart 1.0?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-ngmodel

I have seen many questions discussing about [controller removal](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/commit/5f8e27659ffb0140e0c153f8cecd627df273bfd2) in angular 1.0, so now i like to know how to port controller part to new angular 1.0 code.

Comment: The linked commit does tell it mostly. You have one root controller (rootContext) otherwise use a component.

Comment: Just now i understand component can be used in place of controller, i will try it out in angular 1.0